# tor is frozen (No circuits are opened.)

Tags: connection

Periodicly, the tor daemon is frozen.
In logs I see only this

`No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 121 (a Hidden service: Establishing introduction point 4-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 118930ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway.`

Internet connection is stable.

`Tor 0.4.7.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.35 as libc.`

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Does anyone know something about this issue?